# blue Dio for Bibliography on IOP Journals

Tags: bibliographies, cross-referencing, citing

I found many people asking the same question but I couldn't solve it. I am using iopart document class.
Here are my packages

```
\documentclass[12pt]{iopart}

\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{xurl}

\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[colorlinks, citecolor = blue, urlcolor = blue]{hyperref}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float}
\hbadness=6000
\overfullrule=1pt
\hfuzz=2pt
\pdfoutput=1


\section*{References}
\bibliographystyle{iopart-num}
\bibliography{iopart-num}
```

I am trying to get like this reference with blue color.
[image]

but I am only getting all black!

Comment: `iopart-num` will not produce that kind of reference. Anyway, you need to hand edit the `.bbl` file.

Comment: @egreg I am new to latex so what do you mean by editing .bbl and how? Is there any way to generate this kind automatically?